# How to detect a key sequence in Node.js to perform some action

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an RFID reader that sends a sequence of keystrokes when a card is scanned. I am using `iohook` to listen for key presses and perform some action when a sequence of keys have been pressed.

The exact sequence is this

```
2
1
5
9
4
5
8
1
0
5
5
enter
```

The problem is that I don't know how to check for this sequence. **There are other keys being pressed before and after this sequence.** I tried adding every key press to an array but then my array got very big and I don't know at which point I should clear my array.

Here is my code so far

```
const ioHook = require('iohook')
let keys_pressed = []

ioHook.on("keydown", event => {
  keys_pressed.push(event)
  console.log(keys_pressed)
})

ioHook.start()
```

Comment: "I tried adding every key press to an array."  Could you post the corresponding code so we could have something to talk about?

Comment: I only got as far as keys_pressed.push(event) but not sure if that's the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to detect right sequence as soon as it is entered, you can have your `keys_pressed` array always of the same length (which is the length of a sequence you are looking for) - you don't need to keep more elements in memory than that. Every keystroke, remove oldest element and add newest element, and see if last pressed sequence is the same as the one you are looking for

```
const ioHook = require('iohook')

const predefinedSequence = ['2', '1', '5', '9', '4', '5', '8', '1', '0', '5', '5', 'enter']

const compareSequences = (seq1, seq2) => {
  if (seq1.length !== seq2.length) return false
  for (let i = 0; i < seq1.length; i++) {
    if (seq1[i] !== seq2[i]) return false
  }
  return true
}

// create keys_pressed array of the same length as predefinedSequence
const keys_pressed = new Array(predefinedSequence.length)

ioHook.on("keydown", event => {
  keys_pressed.shift() // remove the oldest item from the start of the array
  keys_pressed.push(event) // push the newest item to the end
  if (compareSequences(predefinedSequence, keys_pressed)) {
    console.log('sequence detected')
  }
})

ioHook.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

In generally probably you need to implementable [Finite-state_machine](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Finite-state_machine)

In this case you can do like this code. Not need hold all data in memory - just 1 value like current state

```js
const pattern = [1,2,1,2,3];

let tmp = [];
let p = -1;
function search(a) {  
  tmp.push(a);
  if (pattern[++p] === a) {  

if (p === pattern.length-1) {
   console.log('pattern is found');       
   p = -1;
   tmp = [];
}
  } else {
   tmp.shift()
   p = tmp.length-1;
  }  
}

for(let a of [1,2,1,2,1,2,3]) search(a);
```

Comment: I think there are multiple traps here. 1) You are looking for the "next" symbol, and if you don't see it, you go back to index 0. What if the symbol you saw was the 1st symbol of the sequence? You should have gone to index 1 instead. 2) OP's sequence has repetitions, therefore there should be multiple "current indices". Imagine the sequence `55567`. When you see `5` three times in a row, you should be looking for `6` or `5` (at many previous indices).

Comment: 1) p is like current position in pattern - not next symbol from input, 2) we hold only state per pattern - not all sequences. This is very simple

Comment: Yes! But there should be two current positions, since it's always possible that the pattern begins "now". The next incoming key might not be the next expected key of the patter, but it can be the first key of the pattern.

Comment: yes, you are right, it is not working for pattern = [1,2,1,2,3], for(let a of [1,2,1,2,1,2,3]) search(a);

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet:

```js
const pattern = [2, 1, 5, 9, 4, 5, 8, 1, 0, 5, 5, 'enter'];

const previousKeys = []; // this will store the recent incoming keys

function checkPattern() { // compares the recent keys with the pattern
  for (let i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
    if (previousKeys[i] !== pattern[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const incomingKeys = [
  9, 9, 9, 9, 4, 5, 8, 1, 0, 5, 5, 'enter',
  2, 1, 5, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 'enter',
  1, 2, 3,
  2, 1, 5, 9, 4, 5, 8, 1, 0, 5, 5, 'enter', // the pattern
  7, 8, 9, 'enter',
];
let nextKeyIndex = 0;

console.log('Sending', incomingKeys.length, 'keys...');

let isPatternFound = false;
while (!isPatternFound && nextKeyIndex < incomingKeys.length) {
  const incomingKey = incomingKeys[nextKeyIndex++];
  previousKeys.push(incomingKey);
  if (previousKeys.length > pattern.length) {
    previousKeys.shift(); // forget the oldest key
  }
  isPatternFound = checkPattern();
}

console.log('Keys recorded:', nextKeyIndex);
console.log('Is pattern found?', isPatternFound);
```